# Can data table do a left join for 3 or more data tables?

Tags: r, data.table, outer-join

I've searched for an answer to this simple question, but can't find a similar question.  I have 3 data tables:

```
set.seed(0)
demo <- data.table(id = 1:10, demo.var = rnorm(10), key = 'id'); demo
lab <- data.table(id = 1:7, tc = rnorm(7), key = 'id'); lab
anthro <- data.table(id = 4:9, bmi = rnorm(6), key = 'id'); anthro
```

All IDs that are in lab and anthro are in the demo data.table, but lab and anthro contain different subsets of the IDs in demo

Both

```
lab[demo]
anthro[demo]
```

give the information I want: all 10 IDs with additional information from either the lab or anthro data.table, but is there a was to merge all 3 together in a similar manner?  I've tried some permutations such as

```
anthro[lab][demo]
```

but this gives the preserves the anthro information only for the IDs that are in the lab data.table - there's no anthro information for IDs 8 and 9

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: +1 for providing the data in a simple to use format for the answers; wish everyone did this.

Comment: `B[A]` does a left-join, not a full outer join... If this is indeed what you're looking for, then probably you could edit the title? (although here since `demo` has all the values you want to join on, it works as intended).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
anthro[lab[demo]]
#      id        bmi         tc     demo.var
#   1:  1         NA  0.7635935  1.262954285
#   2:  2         NA -0.7990092 -0.326233361
#   3:  3         NA -1.1476570  1.329799263
#   4:  4 -0.8919211 -0.2894616  1.272429321
#   5:  5  0.4356833 -0.2992151  0.414641434
#   6:  6 -1.2375384 -0.4115108 -1.539950042
#   7:  7 -0.2242679  0.2522234 -0.928567035
#   8:  8  0.3773956         NA -0.294720447
#   9:  9  0.1333364         NA -0.005767173
#  10: 10         NA         NA  2.404653389
```

The inner table is always the one the outer join is performed on, so this nesting makes sure that the table with the super set of the index values is always the inner table.

Comment: thanks - can't believe how simple the answer is and that it's so obvious after being pointed out to me